# service vsftpd restart : not working

Tags: vsftpd, upstart

I edited /etc/vsftpd.conf on my remote server. Now to restart the vsftpd, I ran

```
ravbholua@ravi:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
[sudo] password for ravbholua: 
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service vsftpd restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop vsftpd ; start vsftpd. The restart(8) utility is also available.
vsftpd stop/waiting
vsftpd start/running, process 4658
```

The above command has already been executed and I see the system works as per the new change.

Now looking at the above command output, I wanted to use service utility. So I changed the configuration file again and ran the below:

```
service vsftpd restart
```

But the above command didn't work (I came to know this as the system fails to behave as per the new change).

Now when I enter the 1st command again , i.e.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

the system behaves as per the latest change.

In nutshell, `sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart` works but not `service vsftpd restart`

Where am I mistaken in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did your command:

```
/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
ps ax |egrep -i ftp
```

My output was :

```
root@mohsen-VirtualBox:/home/mohsen# ps ax |egrep -i ftp
 1710 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
 2736 pts/1    S+     0:00 egrep --color=auto -i ftp
```

Put output of `service command`

Did you get :

```
root@mohsen-VirtualBox:/home/mohsen# service vsftpd restart
vsftpd stop/waiting
vsftpd start/running, process 2752
```

How you find out your vsfpt is not running?

Comment: $ service vsftpd restart
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.23" (uid=1001 pid=5078 comm="stop vsftpd ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.24" (uid=1001 pid=5075 comm="start vsftpd ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="init")
ravbholua@ravi:~$

Comment: oh my GOD, you should add soudo for service command: `sudo service vsftpd restart`

Comment: Great! Thanks for your assistance. Yes sudo is required for the same. May I ask you one related thing: what was happening with the command `service vsftpd restart` ,i.e. without sudo?

Comment: Look at my output please: (Why so many instances running of vsftpd?) ravbholua@ravi:~$ ps ax |egrep -i ftp 
 8123 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
 8126 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
 8127 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
 8133 pts/0    S+     0:00 egrep --color=auto -i ftp
ravbholua@ravi:~$

Comment: @Ravi , sudo just ask you introduce yourself as root, service command need run as root user.

Answer (score 0):

The restart command does not use the new Upstart configuration. There are a few other things it does not do. Please see the following for details: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#restart